# C# UI "Not responding" stops Refresh()

Tags: c#, user-interface, refresh

If the main UI thread takes too long, the window starts "Not responding". This isn't a problem - in fact, it actually has several advantages, such as making the UI not respond, and effectively "caching" input until after the long operation is completed.

However, this state stops Refresh() functions working. Status messages, progress bars etc. stop updating. To clarify, it is NOT simply the long operation itself causing this. I can sit and watch the long operation (takes about a minute) and it all works PERFECTLY. The UI updates upon Refresh correctly, and everything is just peachy.

However, if I left-click the title bar, say, this triggers the "Not responding" state, which for some reason stops any Refreshes from repainting (they are still being called).

Putting the long operation into a BackgroundWorker thread would be one step forward, three steps back. I can live with the progress bar not updating etc., but it would be really nice for it to update correctly, even when "not responding".

Given that the "hung" UI is perfectly happy updating/refreshing/repainting the UI during long operations, surely there is a way to have it keep doing that, even when it is set to "not responding"?

Also, calling Application.DoEvents() has many drawbacks (just as processing messages it should instead cache for later), so I can't do that either.

Comment: Threading is your only solution, you can't expect to perform long operations on the UI thread and expect it to stay responsive. What is the issue with BackgroundWorker? It has a [report progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) method that solves your mentioned queries

Comment: I don't see why the absolutely-standard approach of "Don't do synchronous long-running work in the UI thread" doesn't apply here. In what way would it be "three steps back" to have a responsive UI (which could be minimized, moved etc) while the work is taking place?

Comment: @Sayse: Well, threading *may* not be the only solution. We don't know what the work is. If it's IO-bound, then async/await may be able to keep all the work on one thread, but without blocking.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Very true, either way I don't agree with the OP's arguments against BackgroundWorker

Comment: `Given that the "hung" UI is perfectly happy updating/refreshing/repainting the UI during long operations, surely there is a way to have it keep doing that` Your app is probably not repainting itself. When you see "(Not responding)" in the title bar (Windows) then the OS probably has taken over repainting of that window (using backing store) because the program is not responding

Comment: @Brandin, My app is repainting itself perfectly (with manual calls to Refresh()), right up until the OS decides it isn't responding.

Comment: Also, the unresponsive UI is actually the perfect behaviour. I don't want it to do anything (be edited etc.) while the operation is taking place. And the fact that input is kept in the message queue and process at the end is very useful

Comment: @Athena - It is absolutely not the perfect behaviour because whilst you may find it acceptable, your users will believe your app has crashed which is bad for business and other things... You could use a splash screen that carries out the operation, I used to have a please wait dialog that would open on an action and would close when the action (done on a separate thread) was finished

Comment: @Athena Additionally if user clicks again when "Not responding" is displayed, generally Windows offers the user a chance to kill the app at that point

Answer (score 1):

Best off moving this to a separate thread. Although the behaviour is not without merit, I suspect the maintainability of this solution will eventually force a rethink.

You can get all the 'benefits' by simply displaying a panel over the top of your UI to block out access to all features. On this panel you can show a progress bar and status message so the user doesn't get too freaked.

I think it would be worth the investment now to give a more polished solution.